# pd.ExcelWriter, writer.save(), download file locally

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python 3.7.5 in a databricks environment.

I have a pretty simple function written that concatenates multiple dataframes into one excel spreadsheet.  **The main issue is that I can't access the file to download to my local machine.**

```
# function

def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')  

    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):

        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)  

    writer.save()

 

# list of dataframes and sheet names

dfs = [df, df1, df2]

sheets = ['df','df1','df2']   

 

# run function

dfs_tabs(dfs, sheets, 'filename.xlsx')
```

Here is a sample of how I export dataframes to csv successfully to a location where I can download the files. Hoping that I can merge the logic from below to the function above to be able to download the file to my local machine.

```
#bounce to csv

outname = 'file.csv'

outdir = '/dbfs/FileStore/'

df.to_csv(outdir+outname, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: im on a mac - so none of the above?

Comment: Is your output directory in Databricks dbfs (based on the path you showed)?  If so you will need to use this workaround: https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations

Comment: yes the output directory is in dbfs - thanks for a link to the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations - I had to append the entire local address to the filename variable - complete working script below - thanks @jmcnamara

```
# function

def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')  

    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):

        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)  

    writer.save()

 

# list of dataframes and sheet names

dfs = [df, df1, df2]

sheets = ['df','df1','df2']   

 

# run function

dfs_tabs(dfs, sheets, '/local_disk0/tmp/filename.xlsx')

 

#copy file to dbfs

 

copyfile('/local_disk0/tmp/filename.xlsx', '/dbfs/FileStore/filename.xlsx')
```